# SQL - updating column based on next row value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, and the requirement is to update column 'val' based on the value in the column 'val' in next row (ordered by by id).

Table is shown below :

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | val  | dt         |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | k    | 2021-01-01 |
|  3 | k    | 2021-05-15 |
|  5 | k2   | 2021-10-11 |
+----+------+------------+
```

I'm able get the select query to get the next value, however the update query is not working.

Here is the select query (working fine):

```
select t1.id, t1.val as t1val, t2.val as t2val from ssc t1 inner join (select id, lead(val) over(order by id) as val from ssc) t2 on (t1.id=t2.id);
```

Here is the update query, not working :

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.val = t2.val 
FROM ssc t 
INNER JOIN (select id, lead(val) over(order by id) as val from ssc) t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id
```

Any inputs on how to fix this ?
tia!

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order of clauses are a bit off, the following modification will work

```sql
UPDATE ssc t 
INNER JOIN (select id, lead(val) over(order by id) as val from ssc) t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id
SET t.val = t2.val
```

[View Live Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g13rdBcvdE1r4YKgGSfrU8/1)

You may consider using the following query which also uses the lead function but without the join.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE ssc (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `val` VARCHAR(2),
  `dt` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO ssc
  (`id`, `val`, `dt`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'k', '2021-01-01'),
  ('3', 'k1', '2021-05-15'),
  ('5', 'k2', '2021-10-11');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from ssc;
```

| id | val | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | k | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | k1 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| 5 | k2 | 2021-10-11 00:00:00 |

---

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE ssc t1,
   (
       SELECT t2.id,LEAD(t2.val) OVER (ORDER BY t2.id) as val
       FROM ssc t2
   ) t3
SET t1.val = t3.val
WHERE t1.id = t3.id;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from ssc;
```

| id | val | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | k1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | k2 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| 5 |  | 2021-10-11 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g13rdBcvdE1r4YKgGSfrU8/0)

Let me know if this works for you.